# Programatically recognizing that a windows RDP session is currently in progress

Tags: windows, api, remote-desktop

I have a virtual machine on a remote computer, to which I connect using Windows RDP.
We have several people using this machine, all with the same Windows login.

A problem that often occurs, is that when someone connects to the machine he throws out another person currently connected to it.

I would like to write a small application letting you know if someone is currently using the machine, but I don't know how to use the API in order to achieve this. Please note again that everyone uses the same login.

Any ideas?

Comment: What version of Windows are you connecting to?

Comment: Windows 7, but this application will also have to run on Win XP

Comment: Call the [`GetSystemMetrics` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724385.aspx) and pass the `SM_REMOTESESSION` flag. But wouldn't a better solution be to increase the possible number of concurrent logins for that account so that users aren't booted off in the first place?

Comment: It would be, but company policy does not allow it.Thank you.

Comment: @Cody Gray : How did you run it on remote machine?

Comment: @rkosegi: I don't understand what you're asking. How did I run *what* on a remote machine?

Comment: @Cody Gray : JonEgerton asks for determining remote desktop sessions status on VM on remote computer.GetSystemMetrics runs locally.So, how did you accomplish it without access remote PC?So question how did you run GetSystemMetrics on remote PC to get RDP status?

Comment: @rkosegi: That's apparently not how I interpreted the question. I assumed that he was writing an application to run on the virtual machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use WTSEnumerateSessionsEx function:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee621014%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

You will receive list of sessions.If there some in 'Active' state RDP connection is realy in use.

WTS_CONNECTSTATE_CLASS : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383860%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Similar result you can get with built-in command "QWINSTA"